# Scala: to inherit abstract methods

Tags: scala, methods, abstract, inheritance

I have a class hierarchy like this.

```
abstract class Element {
  var name: String
  var description: String 
}

class Group (var name : String, var description : String, var members: Set[Element] =Set()) 
extends Element{}

trait TypedElement extends Element{ 
  var types: Set[Type] 
}

trait ArchitecturalElement extends PropertyHolderElement with TypedElement

abstract class Component extends ConnectableElement with ArchitecturalElement {
  var subElements : Set[ArchitecturalElement]
 var interactionPoints : Set[InteractionPoint]
}

class SAComponent ( var name :String,
                var description : String,

                var types : Set[Type] = Set(),
                var subElements : Set[ArchitecturalElement] = Set(),
                var interactionPoints : Set[InteractionPoint] = Set()
                ) extends Component
```

Element is the root class of my model.
Now I want to put an abstract method "validate" on Element to be inherited by all my classes. And implemented only in the concrete.
How do I do this?
My validated methods must have different signatures
and some return a value, however others do not return anything.

For example, I would like something like this:

```
 abstract class Element {
  var name: String
  var description: String 
  def validate (elem: Element)
}

class Group (var name : String, var description : String, var members: Set[Element] =Set()) 
extends Element{
validate (gr: Group) = {//the method body}
}

trait TypedElement extends Element{ 
  var types: Set[Type] 
  validate (ty : TypedElement )
}

trait ArchitecturalElement extends PropertyHolderElement with TypedElement {
validate (arel: ArchitecturalElement )
}

abstract class Component extends ConnectableElement with ArchitecturalElement {
  var subElements : Set[ArchitecturalElement]
 var interactionPoints : Set[InteractionPoint]
 validate (el : Component, subElem: Set[ArchitecturalElement]) : Boolean = {//the method body}
 //here, I need the return value to avoid cycles of recursion
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cannot be done.  Overridden methods need to have compatible signatures.  That means the same number of arguments, contravariant in the args, covariant in the return.  That means your args can be supertypes of the overridden args, and the return type can be a subtype of the overridden return type, but they can't vary arbitrarily.

Now you can violate these rules, but then you're not overriding, merely overloading, and you will still need to provide an implementation of the abstract method.